# Android RenderScript FinalizerWatchdogDaemon Fatal Exception

Tags: java, android, renderscript

I use RenderScript in my app to do several image processing tasks.

Sometimes, I randomly get the following exception:

```
10-10 15:27:04.479: E/AndroidRuntime(2113): FATAL EXCEPTION: FinalizerWatchdogDaemon
10-10 15:27:04.479: E/AndroidRuntime(2113): java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: android.renderscript.Type.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds
10-10 15:27:04.479: E/AndroidRuntime(2113):     at android.renderscript.RenderScript.nObjDestroy(RenderScript.java:216)
10-10 15:27:04.479: E/AndroidRuntime(2113):     at android.renderscript.BaseObj.finalize(BaseObj.java:116)
10-10 15:27:04.479: E/AndroidRuntime(2113):     at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:187)
10-10 15:27:04.479: E/AndroidRuntime(2113):     at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:170)
10-10 15:27:04.479: E/AndroidRuntime(2113):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

All my RenderScript-Calls are enclosed by a Semaphore to prevent that the same script is running parallel.
Can anybody tell me what this message means and how I can prevent it?

Comment: what device and OS version are you running on? have you tried using the support library?

Comment: No, no support library, build with minimum-sdk 14. Different devices (Nexus, Asus Transformer, ...), even the emulator.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a very long running kernel?

This thread is attempting to cleanup RS objects when the GC removes the java code reference. If there is a very long running kernel it may be blocked long enough to trigger what you are seeing.  We don't allow objects to be modified by an external thread while a kernel is running, so in effect that external thread is blocked until kernel completion.

Comment: Is there any way of adjusting the timeout? For example, in case I need long-running kernels, can I set it to 20 or 30 seconds?