# android: FATAL EXCEPTION: FinalizerWatchdogDaemon

Tags: android, exception, crash, jakarta-mail

I faced crash in my app like that:

1) Crash

```
E/AndroidRuntime(13087): FATAL EXCEPTION: FinalizerWatchdogDaemon
E/AndroidRuntime(13087): java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.ClientSessionContext.finalize() timed out after 15 seconds
E/AndroidRuntime(13087):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_CTX_free(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(13087):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.AbstractSessionContext.finalize(AbstractSessionContext.java:288)
E/AndroidRuntime(13087):    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:188)
E/AndroidRuntime(13087):    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:171)
E/AndroidRuntime(13087):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

2) Crash

```
E/AndroidRuntime(13456): FATAL EXCEPTION: FinalizerWatchdogDaemon
E/AndroidRuntime(13456): java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager.finalize() timed out after 15 seconds
E/AndroidRuntime(13456):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_shutdown(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(13456):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.close(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:922)
E/AndroidRuntime(13456):    at org.apache.http.impl.SocketHttpClientConnection.shutdown(SocketHttpClientConnection.java:183)
E/AndroidRuntime(13456):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.shutdown(DefaultClientConnection.java:150)
E/AndroidRuntime(13456):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager$PoolEntry.shutdown(SingleClientConnManager.java:440)
E/AndroidRuntime(13456):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager.shutdown(SingleClientConnManager.java:376)
E/AndroidRuntime(13456):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager.finalize(SingleClientConnManager.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(13456):    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:188)
E/AndroidRuntime(13456):    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:171)
E/AndroidRuntime(13456):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
I/CHECKING(13456): Prefs onPause: false
```

Do you have any idea why this crash is going on? I have seen several articles [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-platform/IvLyOohpkls).

3) Crash

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: com.sun.mail.pop3.Protocol.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds
at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(Native Method)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:746)
at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:162)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:142)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:227)
at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(PushbackInputStream.java:146)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readLine(DataInputStream.java:116)
at com.sun.mail.pop3.Protocol.simpleCommand(Protocol.java:413)
at com.sun.mail.pop3.Protocol.quit(Protocol.java:212)
at com.sun.mail.pop3.Protocol.finalize(Protocol.java:133)
at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:187)
at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:170)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: can you post your code of class in which exception occuring

Comment: It is occured various places.

Comment: post for at least one place .

Comment: are you using the https? i mean the url ? if it is ssl oor https then i can give you whole solution

Comment: @Amaresh yes, I`m using ssl and https urls. Please give a clear solution

Comment: For communicating with the server are u using the asynctask?

Comment: Nope, i`m using @Background method of androidannotations, it is created  new BackgroundExecutor.execute(new Runnable(){}).

Comment: ohhkay....can you use volley for the communication becoz it will handle all the types of connections as well....if you are ok theni vl send the whole code so that you can directly use it where ever you need to communicating the server

Comment: Okaayyy )))) Send the whole code If it is possible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90297/discussion-between-nakhmedov-and-amaresh).

Comment: check this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021609/how-to-handle-java-util-concurrent-timeoutexception-android-os-binderproxy-fin] i think this will help you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021609/how-to-handle-java-util-concurrent-timeoutexception-android-os-binderproxy-fin

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300154/android-renderscript-finalizerwatchdogdaemon-fatal-exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300154/android-renderscript-finalizerwatchdogdaemon-fatal-exception)